# how to use tortoise git without a server (local single user)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm looking for a simple tutorial for how to use tortoisegit without any server? I've tried google but, although a lot of people mention you can use tortoisegit without a server, no one explains how to do it so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple:

- Install Git ([msysgit for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/))
- Install [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) and reboot
- go into any directory you want

```
    git init myFirstRepo
    cd myFirstRepo
    echo test> myFirstFile
```

From here, open a Windows explorer and you will the usual icons from files modified, to be added, to be committed, and so on.

[image: TortoiseGit Context Menu]

Answer (score 4):

It's very much the same as with a server, except that all you are then doing is committing your changes to your local repository - there would be no pushing to a remote source.

Comment: thx for the answer but, since i'm a beginner who haven't even used it with a server, i would need more like a step-by-step guide as how to get started

Comment: If you look at GIT hub, there are a number of tutorials: http://help.github.com/.  Tortoise GIT is then just a wrapper to make issueing these commands a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html before going to TortoiseGit. This tutorial explains roughly what git does (not with too much detail, but enough). With this knowledge, you will find it easier to get started with the GUI.